# Pull/push is denied for empty local docker image

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to work with Docker on my local environment, but I assume I have some issues with configuration because I cannot pull/push my local images.

I have this issue even on an empty image; please see the example below.
My Dockerfile is a single line (I have tried different base images as well):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
```

To build this image, I use the command:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile --force-rm -t test .
```

After this, I can see my image in the images list, I also can run local images, but I can't pull/push image, I see the following errors:

[image]

I need the ability to pull images because I need it for Kubernetes deployment (Minikube).

Thanks!

Comment: Please post pull and push commands

Comment: @ViaTech I tried via Docker UI, and the command docker pull test

Comment: What is the actual name of the image?  Do you have a Docker Hub login, or are you trying to push to some private registry?  You won't be able to push an image named just `test` since short names like that are reserved for official images.

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to the repository that will hold your docker image. It's stating that the repository does not exist. Do you have a repository called `test` created somewhere?

You can create one a number of ways, for example: [Docker hub](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/create/), [ECR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/repository-create.html), [Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-portal?tabs=azure-cli)

Comment: Do I need this repository somewhere if I do local stuff?

Comment: If you are using minikube you can load the image in using the load command ```minikube image load my_image```. See: [pushing images](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/pushing/)

Answer (score 0):

First you mentioned you are trying to pull local images, it's not required. After the build image will be saved locally only no need to **pull**.

If you are planning to run it with **minikube** you can use the local images with pushing to any type of repository.

In Kubernetes deployment set the **imagePullPolicy** to **Never** so K8s wont go on the internet to fine the image it will use from **locally**.